# installed plugins are not visible in openfire 3.9.0

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire

i want to archive messages in openfire so i installed openfire 3.9.3 and a plugin in it named monitoring services but unfortunately i dint work

after a lot of research i got to know that monitoring services are not compatible with openfire 3.9.3

so after i installed openfire 3.9.0  but again the result is not as expected

when i install monitoring services plugin in openfire it installed successfully but plugins are not visible and hence not working

any solution to install the plugins

os  ubuntu

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you run Openfire under JAVA 6. But the plugins are compiled with JAVA 7.
Please update java to 7 and restart openfire. You can look up the used JAVA version on the start page in Openfire Admin Console.
Further you should check the Openfire logs.

Comment: yup i got the issue tnx a lot